# Preemptive Cloud Run on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-run, preemption

Is it possible to create a Cloud Run on GKE (Anthos) Kubernetes Cluster with Preemptible nodes and if so can you also enable plugins such as gke-node-pool-shifter and  gke-pvm-killer or will it interfere with cloud run actions such as autoscaling pods

https://hub.helm.sh/charts/rimusz/gke-node-pool-shifter

https://hub.helm.sh/charts/rimusz/gke-pvm-killer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically a Cloud Run on GKE cluster is still a GKE cluster at the end of the day, so it can have preemptive node pools.

However, some Knative Serving components, such as the `activator` and `autoscaler` are in the hot path of serving the requests. You need to make sure they don't end up in a preemptible pool. Similarly, the `controller` and `webhook` are somewhat central to the control plane lifecycle of Knative API objects, so you also need to make sure these pods end up in a non-preemptible node pool.

Secondly, Knative (for now) does not support node selectors or taints/tolerations: https://knative.tips/pod-config/node-affinity/ It simply doesn't give you a way to specify `nodeSelector` or other affinity fields in the Pod template of Knative Service object.

Therefore, you gotta find out a way (like implementing your mutating admission webhook for Knative-created pods) to add such node selectors to the Pods, which is quite tedious.

However, by combining node taints and pd tolerations, I think you can have Knative system components end up in a non-preemptible pool, and everything else (i.e. Knative-created pods) in other nodes (i.e. preemptible nodes).